# Where can I get the UK geo coordinates for locailty / areas?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm looking for the coordinates for UK area's, locality, state/province (part of the problem finding them may be that they don't have a definite name).

I know that postcode coordinates can be obtained under license, but is this the same for area's (e.g. borough's of London). Surely Royal Mail can't charge for these too?

I want to create polygon regions on google maps to show nodes within an area.

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Free Postcode and Ordance Survey Information For EVERYONE

---

Wait until April the 1st. The government are releasing all of this information then.

I will find a link for you.

Read this:
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8402327.stm

> The government is planning to give
> anyone free access to postcode data.
> The move will be made as part of its
> commitment to make more use of
> technology and the web to transform
> official services.
>
> Currently
> organisations that want access to
> datasets that tie postcodes to
> physical locations cannot do so
> without incurring a charge.
>
> Following
> a brief consultation, the postcode
> information is set to be freed in
> April 2010.

Comment: +1 " Data relating to electoral and local authority boundaries as well as postcode areas would be released for free re-use." Govermment announcement 23 dec 09 http://www.communities.gov.uk/news/corporate/1421671

Answer (score 0):

The Office for National Statistics offer a **free** DVD containing the complete set of vector boundaries for the 175,434 [output areas](http://www.statistics.gov.uk/census2001/geo_methods.asp) (think neighbourhoods) in England and Wales.

The DVD is available [here](http://www.statistics.gov.uk/census2001/product_boun_oa_mid_mif.asp).

I think it's worth looking around the OfNS site for the information you're after, but you should be aware that the data set you're after is **extremely** large.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched our shiny new [data.gov.uk](http://data.gov.uk) website and found this

[Urban settlement boundaries](http://data.gov.uk/dataset/urban_settlement_area_boundaries)

CD available [free](http://www.statistics.gov.uk/census2001/product_ua_settle_boun_cd.asp), SHP and MIF

This product contains the complete set of vector (re-usable) boundaries for urban areas and settlements in England and Wales. Boundaries are provided for all the areas of urban land for which Census results have been provided - both urban areas with at least 1,500 residents in 2001 and settlements with fewer than 1,500 residents in 2001 - and allow the exact boundaries (rather than the approximation by Output Areas) of areas of urban land to be loaded into most standard GIS systems.